# How do I save the original $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; on a page that refreshes several times?

Tags: php

I have a page where I need to get the referring URL so I can redirect them back after they compete a form. My problem is, the form has several drop menus and each time a selection is made (prior to submitting the form), the referring URL keeps changing to this page.

I have....

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

And it works only on landing of course.

Now the user selects an option from drop menu and the page refreshes with another drop menu to continue choosing options. Once done, the form I submit to needs to read the original referring URL, not the form page URL.

I need to be able to put the original in a hidden field and submit along with the form options. Thanks for any help. I apologize if this isn't clear, it was difficult to explain.

Comment: Then put it in a hidden field as you suggest, although realize that savvy users can hack the value. You might be better off keeping a session variable server-side instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing it with forms and hidden inputs, that's easy.

```
<input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
```

You could also do it with sessions, though, supposing you use `session_start()`.

```
session_start();// At the very top of your page. Literally THE TOP.

// Set our session variable only if it is not currently set. 
if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer'])) {
    $_SESSION['referrer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

For more on sessions, see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). Sessions were meant for just this sort of thing, taking variables across pages and preserving state.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and help. It seems that the session keeps getting over-ridden each time the form drop menus are used. When it comes time to submit, the original referrer session is gone.

Comment: What do the "drop menus" do? Post the form to the current page or redirect to a new one?

Comment: @Mike also, update you post with some code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: The drop menus allow you to choose options, like.. Select Car. Then it  displays another drop menu... Select Model... then Select Year. Once all 3 drops are selected, it's time to submit so that I can save the info. Currently I have it refresh the page so it reads index.php?car=Honda&make=civic&year=2005 . Are you saying I need to submit the form to index.php and it will no longer override the referring URL?

Comment: Let me see if I can get code. It's a large file. I'll try and gather the related snippets.

Comment: @Mike ahh I see. If you're posting the form with each selection of an option, you will indeed be rewriting the session variable. I've updated my suggestion to fix this by only setting the $_SESSION variable if it is not already set.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_SESSION['GOBACK']=='')
{
  $_SESSION['GOBACK'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

This seems to work. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

When they go to the page save the referrer in a session variable.

After it refreshes and does the page logic, redirect to the session variable you saved.

Comment: Well, I tried it and it does not work :( - The referer is empty once the form is used. Not sure why. It keeps reading reapplying/overriding the session I think.

Comment: Are you sure it's storing the referrer into the session variable?Do you have session_start() at the *top* of the script, on all the pages you are going through?

Comment: Yes. I can see the session when I test, but only on the Landing. Once the drop menus are used, it's overridden. Is there a way to kill that session end storing referring URLs after landing and just save the value?

Comment: I don't understand why the sess option wont work.  As long as you have One, "session_start(); as the first line in the php script" Two, set some $_SESSION['MyVar'] with the referrer, Three, use "session_start();" as the first line of every other page the user will be on, Four, be careful not to overwrite the $_SESSION['MyVar'] it should work.  That's  exactly what it's for  :)  You can write it to a cookie.  Are you familiar with the set up?

Answer (score 0):

Store the referer in the first request into a session variable or a cookie. `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` super globals can help achieve this.

I recommend sessions as the user won't be able to hijack the value locally.